# SQL - returns a incorrect result

Tags: sql, sql-server

in the below table i'm trying to enter the number of times the same status repeated after another status. if the status remains the same and the event status order is sequential then the count shouldn't increase.  if the status change and enters the same status again ,the count should increase

```
   sid status   order   num_times_status_entered_again  Expected result
    1   A       1                     1                               1
    1   A       2                     2                               1 
    1   B       3                     1                               1
    1   C       4                     1                               1
    1   A       5                     3                               2
    1   B       7                     3                               2
    1   B       8                     4                               2
    1   B       9                     5                               2
    1   C       10                    2                               2
    1   A       11                    4                               3
    1   B       13                    7                               3
    1   B       14                    8                               3
    1   B       15                    9                               3
    1   D       16                    1                               1
    1   E       17                    1                               1

    2   A       1                     1                               1
    2   A       2                     2                               1
    2   B       3                     1                               1
    2   B       4                     2                               1
    2   A       5                     3                               2
```

this is the query I'm using

```
update t
set num_times_status_entered_again  = t1.Ncount
from #tableZ t,(select status
count(1) OVER (Partition by status order by status) as Ncount
from #sub_tableZ
where status is not null
group by status, date
) t1 GROUP BY sid
```

Comment: Your expected result does not match your description and part of your description `if the status again` is not readable.  Multiple problems.  Can you firm up that description?

Comment: What if: `if the status remains the same and the event status order is NOT sequential`?  Something should happen with that case, but it's not contained in the description.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?  `SELECT version();`

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU25) (KB5003830) - 14.0.3401.7 (X64) 
 Jun 25 2021 14:02:48 
 Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
 Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: That's not MySQL.  I'll adjust the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a query which generates the required result, I think:

[Fiddle for SQL Server](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8eabb55de670a9a649221e224c69c80c)

`same_stat` and `seq_ord` are derived in the `xrows` CTE term using `CASE ... END` expressions.

`LAG(status) OVER (ORDER BY sid, ord)` provides the `status` value in the previous row based on `sid, ord` ordering.

`LAG(ord   ) OVER (ORDER BY sid, ord)` provides the `ord` value in the previous row based on `sid, ord` ordering, to decide if the last `order value` and the current `order value` have a gap between them.

**For SQL Server:**

```
WITH xrows AS (
        SELECT t.*
             , CASE WHEN status = LAG(status, 1, 'NA') OVER (ORDER BY sid, ord) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS same_stat
             , CASE WHEN ord-1  = LAG(ord   , 1, ord ) OVER (ORDER BY sid, ord) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS seq_ord
          FROM test AS t
     )
SELECT t.*
     , SUM(CASE WHEN same_stat = 1 AND seq_ord = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY sid, status ORDER BY ord) AS xseq
  FROM xrows AS t
 ORDER BY sid, ord
;
```

**For MySQL:**

```
WITH xrows AS (
        SELECT t.*
             , status = COALESCE(LAG(status) OVER (ORDER BY sid, ord) , 'NA')       AS same_stat
             , ord-1  = COALESCE(LAG(ord   ) OVER (ORDER BY sid, ord) ,  ord)       AS seq_ord
          FROM test AS t
     )
SELECT t.*
     , SUM(CASE WHEN same_stat AND seq_ord THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY sid, status ORDER BY ord) AS xseq
  FROM xrows AS t
 ORDER BY sid, ord
;
```

**The result:**

```
+------+--------+------+-----------+---------+------+
| sid  | status | ord  | same_stat | seq_ord | xseq |
+------+--------+------+-----------+---------+------+
|    1 | A      |    1 |         0 |       0 |    1 |
|    1 | A      |    2 |         1 |       1 |    1 |
|    1 | B      |    3 |         0 |       1 |    1 |
|    1 | C      |    4 |         0 |       1 |    1 |
|    1 | A      |    5 |         0 |       1 |    2 |
|    1 | B      |    7 |         0 |       0 |    2 |
|    1 | B      |    8 |         1 |       1 |    2 |
|    1 | B      |    9 |         1 |       1 |    2 |
|    1 | C      |   10 |         0 |       1 |    2 |
|    1 | A      |   11 |         0 |       1 |    3 |
|    1 | B      |   13 |         0 |       0 |    3 |
|    1 | B      |   14 |         1 |       1 |    3 |
|    1 | B      |   15 |         1 |       1 |    3 |
|    1 | D      |   16 |         0 |       1 |    1 |
|    1 | E      |   17 |         0 |       1 |    1 |
|    2 | A      |    1 |         0 |       0 |    1 |
|    2 | A      |    2 |         1 |       1 |    1 |
|    2 | B      |    3 |         0 |       1 |    1 |
|    2 | B      |    4 |         1 |       1 |    1 |
|    2 | A      |    5 |         0 |       1 |    2 |
+------+--------+------+-----------+---------+------+
```

**The setup:**

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    sid         int
  , status      varchar(5)
  , ord         int
);


INSERT INTO test VALUES
  (   1 ,'A'     ,1   )
, (   1 ,'A'     ,2   )
, (   1 ,'B'     ,3   )
, (   1 ,'C'     ,4   )
, (   1 ,'A'     ,5   )
, (   1 ,'B'     ,7   )
, (   1 ,'B'     ,8   )
, (   1 ,'B'     ,9   )
, (   1 ,'C'     ,10  )
, (   1 ,'A'     ,11  )
, (   1 ,'B'     ,13  )
, (   1 ,'B'     ,14  )
, (   1 ,'B'     ,15  )
, (   1 ,'D'     ,16  )
, (   1 ,'E'     ,17  )
 
, (   2 ,'A'     ,1   )
, (   2 ,'A'     ,2   )
, (   2 ,'B'     ,3   )
, (   2 ,'B'     ,4   )
, (   2 ,'A'     ,5   )
;
```

Comment: status is varchar and `status = COALESCE(LAG(status) OVER (ORDER BY sid, ord) , 'NA')       AS same_stat`  return a int in your table. it's not working for me

Comment: and how did you got 1's and 0's for same_stat & seq_ord columns

Comment: @Maddy That's because you tagged the question with `MySQL`, instead of `SQL-Server`.  I've corrected the tags in the question.  MySQL supports the expressions I used in the original answer.  I've updated the answer with the corresponding SQL-Server solution too.  I've kept the MySQL version in the answer as reference.  Both are valid solutions for their respective engines.

Comment: @Maddy For MySQL, a boolean expression, like `x < y` or `x = y` or just the literals `true` and `false`, will evaluate to 0 (`false`), 1 (`true`) or null.  Some other databases require an explicit conversion to produce the corresponding integer values.

Comment: It's working and the logic you used was pretty clear to understand . Thank you so much.